# Wordpress How to make Slider Full-Width (Metaslider)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider

When I switch off the blog part and sidebars in the terrifico theme in Wordpress I don't seem to be able to place a full width slider anywhere.

The theme looks like this in the form that I'm talking about: http://vpthemes.com/preview/Terrifico/page-full-width/

As you can see all the text is 'bounded' by a box (the black line). Is there any way in which I can make the metaslider go OUTSIDE of this box (i.e. to span the FULL width of the page)? I don't necessarily want to get rid of the box all toghether, the text can stay within it.

I have seen on the Metaslider website that some solutions for certain themes are given ([here](https://www.metaslider.com/documentation/full-browser-width-meta-slider-using-template-includes/) - but I am not sure how to adapt this to the theme that I'm using.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disclaimer

Before I suggest a solution, I'd like to point out that what you're asking is to break the Box flow model. I wouldn't recommend that because you're likely to run into inconsistent results across browsers.

That said, what you're trying to accomplish *is possible*. You could use javascript to do this and it may in fact be easier in some respects but here's a CSS solution.

### 1. Break out of the box model

```css
float: left;
width: 200%;
margin-left: -50%;
text-align: center;
```

> The **[float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)** CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

The **width** of the container is still relative to its parent so if you use % units to scale it up you would need to compensate for the responsiveness of the parent. Here, I'm just overcompensating.

To ensure that our element remains centered, we use a negative **margin** that is half of the overflow. That is, we want our box to be 100% wide, we have 100% overflow to ensure that so half the overflow is 50% (comment below if that doesn't make sense).

We use **text-align** to put the element we add in step 3 in the center of the viewport.

### 2. Allow Overflows

This is where you may well break themes. The parent elements will hide elements that float outside of them if they have the `overflow: hidden` property (note `overflow` can also be used to show scrollbars).

You will need to ensure that the parent elements have:

```css
#post-body, .content-posts-wrap {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

As far as I can see that affects `#post-body` and `.content-posts-wrap`

### 3. Add an element that will be the right size

Now we have an oversized container for our slider but we need it to be the width of the page. Inside the div or whatever it is you want to put your slider into you will need to nest another element that will be the correct width. That element will need the following css:

```css
display: inline-block;
width: 100vw;
text-align: left;
```

You need **display** because we are back to the box model now and we want our block to obey the width rule we give to it.

We set our **width** using `vw` ([viewport width](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/length.html)) units to make this a bit easier (but they may not be supported [on your target browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)). There may be some ingenius way to do this without vw units but I would probably just use javascript if it's not an option for you.

Finally, since we set our **text-align** above, we need to reset it here.

### 4. Add a Clearing Div

Because you've broken out of the flow, elements aren't too sure what to do. You probably want to add another element after your parent slider that

> specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

It can be as simple as a `<div>` element with:

```css
clear: both
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works now! Unfortunately it does indeed have the consequence that things differ somewhat per browser. Also what is a little bit of a problem is that there is still a space above the slider (where the black box lines are also visible) and I'm not sure how I can get rid of this.  I do appreciate your help very much though! I will award you the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: Try setting top `margin` and `padding` to 0 on the two elements to get rid of those black box lines - you should be able to get rid of those. Make the browser developer tools your friend though, it makes figuring out which is the offending element really easy.

Comment: Thanks again, will try!

Answer (score 0):

write your code something like this...

html like that...

```
 <div  id="parent_for_slider">
        <div id="slider">
            //place your slider code
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css for that

```
#parent_for_slider{
position:relative;
}

#slider{
position:absolute;
width:100% !important;
height:auto;
}
```

i am recommending to use [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com/) for full width slider with responsiveness

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work. What happens is that my woocommerce shop moves up and now the products and slider overlap and that the width is still the width of the bounded box (i.e. not full-width). Any other solutions? Would the slider that you posted the link to work without problems?